# Clear Solr indices

Tags: ruby-on-rails, solr, sunspot

Hope someone can give some ideas.

I have a Rails app that use Sunspot gem to interact with Solr. I want to remove some indices but because the existing Solr size is massive (almost 35GB), I hesitate to run full reindexing. Is there anyway to drop some indices without running a full reindex, either via Sunspot or directly access Solr?Most of the recommendations I found are to run full reindex.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look here https://github.com/sunspot/sunspot#reindexing-objects

This tell you could reindex only an specific model or records in order to avoid full reindex.

All of your data is coming from different models?

Comment: oh bugger, I overlooked that documentation. No, I only have one model but because I made the changes in schema, I must run full reindex no matter what. Thanks

Comment: It makes sense. Cheers!